# Publish public GPG key on GitHub

Tags: gnupg, github

Is it safe to publish your public GPG keys on GitHub?

And link to them in the signature of the e-mails you send, together with the fingerprint after the link?

Comment: Safe from what?

Comment: @MechMK1 that's a good question. Is it a good practice to do so? Maybe safe from having the key corrupted, by external persons or by GitHub itself?

Comment: In the worst case, your distributed public key is replaced with that of a third party. This has not happened on Github, as far as I know.